# CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android // Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: android, apache, cordova, phonegap

I installed cordova and create a new project.

But when I use this command to add android platform, this error appears.

[image: Error]

Can someone help me with this? I've no idea of where to start, I've tried to use all the android APIs but nothing solves this, besides there's a ENOENT error code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a cordova platform android "6.0", as the Cordova versions usually have 3 digits. Try either of these:

```
cordova platform add android /* get latest version */
cordova platform add android@6.3.0 /* get 6.3.0 */
```

Also, version 6.0(.0) is too old, cordova-android is now in version 7.1.0 or 8.0.0 if I remember correctly. If you use obsolete cordova or cordova-android versions, some plugins could fail to install/work properly.